# forkJoin.subscribe with ReplaySubject is not called

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I would like to create an Observable, which fires if both ReplaySubject instances are holding a value. I tried it like this:

```
let v1 = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
let v2 = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

v1.next('X');

const combo = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(v1, v2)

combo.subscribe( arr => console.log(arr) )

v1.subscribe( s => console.log('v1', s) );
v2.subscribe( s => console.log('v2', s) );

v2.next('Y');
```

Both `v1.subscribe` and `v2.subscribe` is called, but not `combo.subscribe`. What do I wrong? How is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) will only emit an array of all last values of the input observables once all of them complete. If you manually complete `v1` and `v2`, `combo` will emit:

```js
let v1 = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();
let v2 = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();

v1.next('X');
v2.next('Y');
v2.next('Z'); // This additional value should demonstrate the idea of forkJoin

const combo = rxjs.forkJoin(v1, v2)
combo.subscribe( arr => console.log(arr) )

v1.complete();
v2.complete();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

You might be looking for [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) instead if you don't want the inner observables to complete:

```js
let v1 = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();
let v2 = new rxjs.ReplaySubject();

v1.next('X');
v2.next('Y');

const combo = rxjs.combineLatest(v1, v2)
combo.subscribe( arr => console.log(arr) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

forkJoin waits for input observables to complete, then emit last item emitted. You have to complete both subject.